# Designing a GUI in Java that runs itself

Tags: swing, user-interface, draw

I've created a program that scatters three subclasses of "point" randomly across a 100 x 100 grid: sugars, ants, and spiders. The ants move towards the sugar, and the spiders move towards the ants, and when the ants have eaten all the sugar, they run away from the spiders. I have a "while" loop that moves the ants at most one unit and the spiders at least two units every turn. The ants are inevitably all consumed, which terminates the "while" loop. Now, I'd like to represent this program visually with a GUI, and I'm not sure how to go about doing it. I'm pretty sure I need to set the pane layout to "null" so that I'm not forced to use only one object per area. Beyond that, I'm not too sure.

I'll post all the code, but it's a bit verbose. What I really want to know is how to represent all the instances of all these types of points at once, and how to move them according to the principle of the game class' "while" loop (by itself, without a human clicking "next turn," all the way until there are no ants left).

```
public class Sugar extends Point {
private double calories; 
private double calories;
private boolean eaten;
private int antsEating;
private boolean isPoisonous;
public Sugar(double inX, double inY, double inCal, boolean poison) {
    super(inX, inY);
    x = inX;
    y = inY;
    moveable = false;
    calories = inCal;
    eaten = false;
    antsEating = 0;
    isPoisonous = poison;
}
public double getCalories() {
    return this.calories;
}
public boolean eatenYet() {
    return this.eaten;
}
public double getEaters() {
    return this.antsEating;
}
public void antCounter() {
    ++antsEating;
}
public void eaten() {
    this.eaten = true;
}
public boolean findPoison() {
    return this.isPoisonous;
}
```

}

```
public class Ant extends Point{
private double ID;
private double calCount;
private boolean poisoned;
private int spidersEating;

public Ant(double inX, double inY, double identity) {
    super(inX, inY);
    this.x = inX;
    this.y = inY;
    this.moveable = true;
    this.ID = identity;
    this.calCount = 0;
    this.poisoned = false;
    this.spidersEating = 0;
}

public double getID() {
    return this.ID;
}

public double getCalCount() {
    return this.calCount;
}

public boolean wasPoisoned() {
    return this.poisoned;
}

public double getPredators() {
    return this.spidersEating;
}

public double distanceToSugar(Sugar sweet) {
    return this.distance(sweet);
}

public void setCalCount(double food) {
    this.calCount += food;
}

public void toxify() {
    this.poisoned = true;
}

public void feeding(Sugar aSugar) {
    if (this.distance(aSugar) < 0.01) {
        aSugar.antCounter();
    }
}

public void spiderCounter() {
    ++spidersEating;
}

public void eatSugar(Sugar aSug) {
    aSug.eaten();
    if (aSug.findPoison()) {
        this.toxify();
    }
}

public double closestSugarDist(ArrayList<Sugar> sugars) {
    double sugarDist = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < sugars.size(); i++) {
        if (this.distanceToSugar(sugars.get(i)) < sugarDist) {
            sugarDist = this.distanceToSugar(sugars.get(i));
        }
    }
    return sugarDist;
}

public Sugar getClosestSugar(ArrayList<Sugar> sugars) {
    Sugar sucrose = new Sugar(0, 0, 0, false);
    double sugarDist = this.closestSugarDist(sugars);
    for (int i = 0; i < sugars.size(); i++) {
        if (sugarDist == this.distanceToSugar(sugars.get(i))) {
            sucrose = sugars.get(i);
        }
    }
    return sucrose;
}

public void moveAnt(Sugar aSugar) {
    double sugarDistX = (aSugar.getX() - this.getX());
    double sugarDistY = (aSugar.getY() - this.getY());
    double sugarDistZSquare = ((sugarDistX * sugarDistX) + (sugarDistY * sugarDistY));
    double sugarDistZ = Math.sqrt(sugarDistZSquare);
    double newX = (sugarDistX/sugarDistZ);
    double newY = (sugarDistY/sugarDistZ);
    if (this.distance(aSugar) < 1) {
        this.translate(sugarDistX, sugarDistY);
    }
    else {
        this.translate(newX, newY);
    }

    System.out.println("Ant " + this.ID + " is at: " + this.toString());
    System.out.println("Ant " + this.ID + " ate this much: " + this.getCalCount());
}

public Spider averageSpider(ArrayList<Spider> spiders) {
    Spider spy = new Spider(0, 0, 0);
    double spyX = 0;
    double spyY = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < spiders.size(); ++i) {
        spyX += spiders.get(i).getX();
        spyY += spiders.get(i).getY();
    }
    spyX = (spyX / spiders.size());
    spyY = (spyY / spiders.size());
    spy.translate(spyX, spyY);
    return spy;
}

public void runAway(Spider aSpider) {
    double spiderDistX = (aSpider.getX() - this.getX());
    double spiderDistY = (aSpider.getY() - this.getY());
    double spiderDistZSquare = ((spiderDistX * spiderDistX) + (spiderDistY * spiderDistY));
    double spiderDistZ = Math.sqrt(spiderDistZSquare);
    double newX = -(spiderDistX/spiderDistZ);
    double newY = -(spiderDistY/spiderDistZ);
    if (this.distance(aSpider) < 1) {
        this.translate(spiderDistX, spiderDistY);
    }
    else {
        this.translate(newX, newY);
    }

    System.out.println("Ant " + this.ID + " is at: " + this.toString());
    System.out.println("Ant " + this.ID + " ate this much: " + this.getCalCount());
}
```

}

```
public class Spider extends Point{
private double ID;
private double spiCalCount;

public Spider(double inX, double inY, double identity) {
    super(inX, inY);
    this.x = inX;
    this.y = inY;
    this.moveable = true;
    this.ID = identity;
    this.spiCalCount = 0;
}

public double getID() {
    return this.ID;
}

public void setSpiCalCount(double food) {
    this.spiCalCount += food;
}

public double getSpiCalCount() {
    return this.spiCalCount;
}

public double distanceToAnt(Ant ant) {
    return this.distance(ant);
}

public void feeding(Ant ant) {
    if (this.distance(ant) < 0.01) {
        ant.spiderCounter();
    }
}

public void eatAnt(Ant ant) {
    ant.toxify();
}

public double closestAntDist(ArrayList<Ant> ants) {
    double antDist = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < ants.size(); i++) {
        if (this.distanceToAnt(ants.get(i)) < antDist) {
            antDist = this.distanceToAnt(ants.get(i));
        }
    }
    return antDist;
}

public Ant getClosestAnt(ArrayList<Ant> ants) {
    Ant worker = new Ant(0, 0, 0);
    double antDist = this.closestAntDist(ants);
    for (int i = 0; i < ants.size(); i++) {
        if (antDist == this.distanceToAnt(ants.get(i))) {
            worker = ants.get(i);
        }
    }
    return worker;
}

public void moveSpider(Ant ant) {
    double antDistX = (ant.getX() - this.getX());
    double antDistY = (ant.getY() - this.getY());
    double antDistZSquare = ((antDistX * antDistX) + (antDistY * antDistY));
    double antDistZ = Math.sqrt(antDistZSquare);
    //changes these to include the spiCalCount
    double newX = (2 + (this.getSpiCalCount() / 5)) * (antDistX/antDistZ);
    double newY = (2 + (this.getSpiCalCount() / 5)) * (antDistY/antDistZ);
    //change this to include spiCalCount
    if (this.distance(ant) < (2 + (this.getSpiCalCount() / 5))) {
        this.translate(antDistX, antDistY);
    }
    else {
        this.translate(newX, newY);
    }

    System.out.println("Spider " + this.ID + " is at: " + this.toString());
    System.out.println("Spider " + this.ID + " ate this much: " + this.getSpiCalCount());
}
```

}

```
public class Game {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 3) {
        System.err.println("You can't have more than three parameters!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (args.length < 3) {
        System.err.println("You can't have less than three parameters!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.err.println("Please only enter integers.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < args.length; ++j) {
        if (!(Integer.parseInt(args[j]) > 0)) {
            System.err.println("Please enter only positive integers.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    int Ant = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int Sug = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int Spi = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    ArrayList<Ant> antList = new ArrayList<Ant>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Ant; ++i) {
        double hunna = (Math.random() * 100);
        double newHun = (Math.random() * 100);
        antList.add(new Ant(hunna, newHun, i));
        //antList.add(new Ant(0, 0, i));
    }

    ArrayList<Sugar> sugarList = new ArrayList<Sugar>();
    for (int j = 0; j < Sug; ++j) {
        double hunna = (Math.random() * 100);
        double newHun = (Math.random() * 100);
        double fiddy = (Math.random() * 4 + 1);
        boolean toxin = getRandomBoolean();


        sugarList.add(new Sugar(hunna, newHun, fiddy, toxin));
    }

    ArrayList<Spider> spiderList = new ArrayList<Spider>();
    for (int k = 0; k < Spi; ++k) {
        double hunna = (Math.random() * 100);
        double newHun = (Math.random() * 100);
        spiderList.add(new Spider(hunna, newHun, k));
    }
    feedingTime(antList, sugarList, spiderList);
}

public static void feedingTime(ArrayList<Ant> ants, ArrayList<Sugar> sugars, ArrayList<Spider> spiders) {
    int counter = 0;

    while (ants.size() > 0) {
        ++counter;
        //moves the spiders
        for (int a = 0; a < spiders.size(); a++) {
            Ant closeAnt = (spiders.get(a).getClosestAnt(ants));
            spiders.get(a).moveSpider(closeAnt);
        }
        //counts how many spiders are feeding on each ant
        for (int b = 0; b < spiders.size(); b++) {
            Ant closeAnt = (spiders.get(b).getClosestAnt(ants));
            spiders.get(b).feeding(closeAnt);
        }
        //poisons ants if they are too close to the spiders, marks eaten ants as "poisoned"
        for (int c = 0; c < spiders.size(); c++) {
            Ant closeAnt = (spiders.get(c).getClosestAnt(ants));
            if (spiders.get(c).distanceToAnt(closeAnt) < 0.01) {
                spiders.get(c).eatAnt(closeAnt);
                spiders.get(c).setSpiCalCount((closeAnt.getCalCount())/(closeAnt.getPredators()));
            }
        }
        //clears away any spider-poisoned ants
        killAnts(ants);
        //does the same thing but with ants instead of spiders and sugar instead of ants
        if (sugars.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ants.size(); i++) {
                Sugar closeSug = (ants.get(i).getClosestSugar(sugars));
                ants.get(i).moveAnt(closeSug);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < ants.size(); j++) {
                Sugar closeSug = (ants.get(j).getClosestSugar(sugars));
                ants.get(j).feeding(closeSug);
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < ants.size(); k++) {
                Sugar closeSug = (ants.get(k).getClosestSugar(sugars));
                if (ants.get(k).distanceToSugar(closeSug) < 0.01) {
                    ants.get(k).eatSugar(closeSug);
                    ants.get(k).setCalCount((closeSug.getCalories())/(closeSug.getEaters()));
                }
            }
        }
        //after all the sugar has been eaten, the ants run away from the spider
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < ants.size(); i++) {
                Spider spyder = (ants.get(i).averageSpider(spiders));
                ants.get(i).runAway(spyder);
            }
        }
        //clears away all sugar-poisoned ants and eaten sugar
        killAnts(ants);
        removeSugar(sugars);
    }
    Spider fatSpi = (fattestSpider(spiders));
    System.out.println("The fattest Spider is: " + fatSpi.getID() + " with cals: " + fatSpi.getSpiCalCount());
    System.out.println("Turns executed: " + counter);
}


public static void removeSugar(ArrayList<Sugar> sugars) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < sugars.size()) {
        if (!(sugars.get(i).eatenYet())) {
            ++i;
        }
        else {
            sugars.remove(i);
        }
    }
}

public static void killAnts(ArrayList<Ant> ants) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < ants.size()) {
        if (!(ants.get(i).wasPoisoned())) {
            ++i;
        }
        else {
            ants.remove(i);
        }
    }
}

public static Spider fattestSpider(ArrayList<Spider> someSpiders) {
    double cals = -1;
    Spider dummySpi = new Spider (0,0,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < someSpiders.size(); ++i) {
        if (someSpiders.get(i).getSpiCalCount() > cals) {
            cals = someSpiders.get(i).getSpiCalCount();
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < someSpiders.size(); ++j) {
        if (someSpiders.get(j).getSpiCalCount() == cals) {
            return someSpiders.get(j);
        }
    }
    return dummySpi;
}

public static boolean getRandomBoolean() {
    return Math.random() < 0.5;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past, and one point I would make is to not extend from Point, and rather have something like this :

```
class Sugar {

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        ...
    }
}


class Spider{

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        ...
    }
}


class Ant{

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The reason is, what if at some later point in time instead of a point, you want to draw a line, or an image of a spider or ant?

Its also better to have this kind of strategy pattern in general. The types need to know how to draw themselves.